# Add a custom/programmed block to a CMS page

Tags: blocks, custom, cms, page, router

I have created a page using the CMS (via Admin Portal) and now I want to add a custom block (programmed) to the page. 
You can see the created page here: 
[image]

My structure is the following:

[image]

but unfortunately I do not get the created CMS page with the block connected. 
I thought that maybe the Router ID has to be set to cms. But I don't know exactly how to adjust the files accordingly.
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using module you can add your block  like this.

Add in your layout file

**summary_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
             <block class="VenAbf\ModAbf\Block\Index" name="call_block_name" template="VenAbf_ModAbf::testinase.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Using admin panel go to you cms page and click on edit and add this line and click on save

```
{{block class="VenAbf\ModAbf\Block\Index" template="VenAbf_ModAbf::testinase.phtml"}}
```

> Please run magento command after adding above code.

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
```

**I Hope This Helps You.**